# How to pass same class method inside onActivityResult() in android?

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I have one method - `addEntryData`. I want to pass the `addEntryData` method inside `onActivityResult`.

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent );
    // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2
    if(requestCode==2) {I want ot put my addEntryData method here.}
}

public void addEntryData(SMSForwardEntry smsForwardEntry)
{
    smsForwardEntries.add(smsForwardEntry);
    smsForwardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    saveData();
    Analytics.track(AnalyticsEvents.SMS_FORWARD_ADDED);
}
```

Comment: i don't thing you will get any issue call function there if addEntryData method in same activity, and SMSForwardEntry coming from intent
And 
follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `startActivityForResult()`

Example:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);

// add data that you want to pass to other activity in to Intent

startActivityForResult(i, LAUNCH_SECOND_ACTIVITY);
```

and in SecondActivity you can get same Intent using `getIntent()`.

And from SecondActivity return result using:

`setResult(RESULT_OK); .....`

and handle it in `onActivityResult()`

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
 {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent );
    // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2
    if(requestCode==2) {
         addEntryData(smsForwardEntry);//Add like this
    }
 }

 public void addEntryData(SMSForwardEntry smsForwardEntry) {
    smsForwardEntries.add(smsForwardEntry);
    smsForwardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    saveData();
    Analytics.track(AnalyticsEvents.SMS_FORWARD_ADDED);
}
```